# Is it safe to use GCD with code that also makes asynchronous calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that does some complex work building data for a HTTP request, currently the the request itself (using AFNetworking) is also part of the method that will be wrapped by `dispatch_async`. Is it better to refactor things so that the AFNetworking call is not wrapped?

```
// expensive set up code then...
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation =
            [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                 NSLog(@"response %@", responseObject);
                                                 success(responseObject);
                                             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                                                failure(error);
                    }];

    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:requestOperation];
    return requestOperation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what thread you call it on. AFNetworking will create the request operation on its own queue, and call the completion handlers on the main queue.